# Django URL error

Tags: python, django

Error:

Reverse for 'charges_report' with arguments '(u'rtcl', datetime.date(2012, 1, 3), datetime.date(2012, 1, 4), u'')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

in my urls.py

```
   url(r'^charges_report/(?P<company_name>[\s\w\d-]+)/(?P<start_date>[\s\w\d-]+)         /(?P<close_date>[\s\w\d-]+)/(?P<batch_no>[\s\w\d-]+)/$', 
                                'admin.reports.views.charges_report',
                                name='charges_report'),
```

and in my form views on POST

When user submits form the error is occurring. I mean on request.POST, Here is the code for form submit

```
      if request.POST:
        company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST, request=request)

         if company_form.is_valid():
           company_name =  company_form.cleaned_data['company_name']
           start_date = company_form.cleaned_data['start_date']
           close_date = company_form.cleaned_data['close_date']
           batch_no = company_form.cleaned_data['batch_no']


        #if 'immigration_charges' in request.POST:

        return        HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('charges_report',args=[company_name, start_date, close_date, batch_no]))
```

in views

```
  def charges_report(request, company_name, start_date, close_date, batch_no=None,):
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Are you saying that when you call your app with a certain URL, then Django gives an error "keyword arguments '{}' not found"?  Could you give us the exact test case and the exact error message text please?

Comment: I have url called charges_report which takes 4 parameters. These 4 parameters are coming from form. When user submits these 4 four parameter from the form then which will redirect to charges_report. Now what if the user doesn't provided last parameter (last parameter is optional) then I'm getting error.

Comment: Which part of the code is triggering the error? The exact error message text will likely include a stack trace, which will tell where the error was raised.

Comment: When user submits form the error is occurring. I mean on request.POST,

Comment: I repeat, which part of the code is triggering the error? I mean, exactly which line, and exactly which expression, in exactly which function?  It's important that you provide information, you can't expect us to read your mind or your screen.

Comment: I edited the source code in above section. See i have form which consist of 4 fields, out of which 3 are required and last parameter i,e batch_no is optional(not required). If user submits all the four parameter the form redirection is working fine. But if user submits only the required fields (first 3 fields) then form is not redirecting to another function (view). Its giving NoReverseMatch error

Comment: Gradually you are revealing what we need to know to be able to answer your question. You might find it helpful to read "[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)" for guidance on what else to reveal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is taking keyword arguments, but you are passing positional arguments in `reverse`.

Try:

```
  kwargs = dict()
  kwargs['company_name'] = company_name
  kwargs['start_date'] = start_date
  kwargs['close_date'] = close_date
  kwargs['batch_no'] = batch_no
  return HttpResponse(reverse('charges_report',kwargs=kwargs))
```

You also need to format your dates to match the regular expression in your URL pattern. Right now you are passing the literal string `datetime.date(2012, 1, 3)` as the `start_date`.

Change `start_date` (and `close_date`) to something that matches your regular expression, something like this:

```
kwargs['start_date'] = "{}".format(start_date)
kwargs['close_date'] = "{}".format(close_date)
```

Comment: Still I'm getting same error                                                           Reverse for 'charges_report' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'start_date': datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), 'close_date': datetime.date(2012, 1,31), 'batch_no': u'', 'company_name': u'rtcl'}' not found.

Answer (score 0):

The [Django URL dispatch documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) cautions that:

- "If there are any errors whilst importing any of your view functions, it will cause reverse() to raise an error, even if that view function is not the one you are trying to reverse."
- "Make sure that any views you reference in your URLconf files exist and can be imported correctly."
- "Do not include lines that reference views you haven't written yet."  -

One of these may be your problem.

Comment: I have url called charges_report which takes 4 parameters. These 4 parameters are coming from form. When user submits these 4 four parameter from the form then which will redirect to charges_report. Now what if the user doesn't provided last parameter (last parameter is optional) then I'm getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a kwarg dictionary instead of positional arguments.